# Make test using sinon stub for function using Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, mocha.js, sinon

I want to make a Test Case using Sinon stub Promise

If i am not resolving from my code then test should fail but currently it is passing.

```
var sendMail = function (templateName, recipients, templateParameters, attachments, subject) {

return mailingExternalTemplateModel.findMailingTemplateId(templateName)
    .then( (result) => {
        var params = {
            "FromEmail": nodeMailjet.mailjetFromMail,
            "FromName": nodeMailjet.mailjetFromName,
            "Subject": subject,
            'MJ-TemplateID': result,
            'MJ-TemplateLanguage': true,
            "Recipients": recipients,
            "Vars": {
                'username': templateParameters.username,
                'hello': i18n.__('email.hello'),
                'voucher_details': i18n.__('email.voucher_details'),
                'email_footer': i18n.__('email.footer.i_love_my_price')
            }
        };

        if (attachments) {
            params.Attachments = attachments;
        }

        return mailjet
            .post("send")
            .request(params)
            .then((result) => {
                return result.body; //***** If i comment here then still test case goes green which should fail. so how i achive that?
            });
    })
    .catch( (err) => {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    });
};
```

If I comment out `return result.body;`, which mean the Promise don't return, the test should fail. But it is not happening.

Test case:

```
var sinonStubPromise = require('sinon-stub-promise');
sinonStubPromise(sinon);

it('it should send mail successfully', function(done) {

    var findMailingTemplateIdStub = sinon.stub(mailingExternalTemplateModel, 'findMailingTemplateId');

    findMailingTemplateIdStub.returnsPromise().resolves(88888);

    var successResponse = {'successId': 989890};

    var request = sinon.stub().returnsPromise().resolves(successResponse);

    sinon.stub(mailjet, "post", function () {
        return {
            request: request
        }
    });

    mailSender.sendMail(templateName, recipients, templateParams, attachments, 'thats subject')
        .then((returnVal) => {
            assert.deepEqual(
                returnVal,
                successResponse
            );
        })
        .catch((err) => {

        })

    done();
});
```

Comment: Why - vote? i can't understand? this is a perfect question...

Comment: Try moving the done(); call inside the then after your assert

Comment: @wietsevenema it will give error  Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

Comment: If you're testing promise-based code, don't use `done` but use Mocha's [built-in promise support](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises). Also, your test is swallowing any errors thrown by `assert.deepEqual()` because of an empty `catch` handler.

Comment: @robertklep can you give answer of this question? thanks in advance.

Comment: @ApoorvaShah yes, I just posted an answer to explain a few things :)

Comment: Try replacing the .catch with .then(done,done) 
it will at least show you the error.

Answer (score 1):

Without testing with your code extensively, I can offer the following advise that might solve your problem: firstly, [Mocha supports promises](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises), which works much better when you want to test promises-based code than using `done`.

Also, if the assertion fails (which throws an error), the error is never handled (it's "swallowed"), partly because you added an empty `.catch()`. This can't be solved by adding `done` after the assertion, because it will never get called (because of the error being thrown).

Try the following:

```
it('it should send mail successfully', function() {
  ...
  return mailSender.sendMail(templateName, recipients, templateParams, attachments, 'thats subject')
         .then((returnVal) => {
           assert.deepEqual(
             returnVal,
             successResponse
           );
         });
});
```

Notice how `done` isn't used at all anymore, and instead the promise returned by `mailSender.sendMail` is returned to Mocha.

Comment: yes done is not required here but can you please give answer about:
if i comment line
return result.body; 

then my test should fail. but currently test is passing.

Comment: @ApoorvaShah can you check what `returnVal` is? I assume it's `undefined` if you leave out `return result.body`.

Comment: This style is kind of tricky also. If you forget to type 'return' your test will always be green.

Comment: @wietsevenema you'd most likely get an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` if you forget the `return`. Still, using Mocha's built-in promise assertions is much less error-prone than using the callback-style with `done`.

Comment: @robertklep 

returnVal i get
{
  "successId": 989890
}

mostly because in test case i have written

    var successResponse = {'successId': 989890};

    var request = sinon.stub().returnsPromise().resolves(successResponse);

Comment: @ApoorvaShah are you sure that the `.then()` that (doesn't) return the `result.body` is called?

Comment: now i changed to 
findMailingTemplateIdStub.returns(Promise.resolve(88888));

Answer (score 1):

Now i changed my code to following and its working.

major change is

```
findMailingTemplateIdStub.returnsPromise().resolves(88888); change to
findMailingTemplateIdStub.returns(Promise.resolve(88888));
```

and

```
var request = sinon.stub().returnsPromise().resolves(successResponse);
changed to var request = sinon.stub().returns(Promise.resolve(successResponse));

   it('it should send mail successfully', function(done) {

    var findMailingTemplateIdStub = sinon.stub(mailingExternalTemplateModel, 'findMailingTemplateId');

    findMailingTemplateIdStub.returns(Promise.resolve(88888));

    var successResponse = {
        'body': {
                    Sent:
                    [
                      {
                          Email: 'test@example.com',
                          MessageID: '188589580585481212'
                      }
                    ]
                }
    };

    var request = sinon.stub().returns(Promise.resolve(successResponse));

    sinon.stub(mailjet, "post", function () {
        return {
            request: request
        }
    });

    mailSender.sendMail(templateName, recipients, templateParams, attachments, 'thats subject')
        .then((returnVal) => {
            assert.deepEqual(returnVal, successResponse.body);
            done();
        })
        .catch((err) => {
                done(err);
            }
        );
});
```